# What is wrong for my form for this shallow route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

here is my route

```
resources :games do
  resources :message_templates, :shallow => true
```

my rake routes is like this

```
                  game_message_templates GET    /games/:game_id/message_templates(.:format)              message_templates#index
                                         POST   /games/:game_id/message_templates(.:format)              message_templates#create
               new_game_message_template GET    /games/:game_id/message_templates/new(.:format)          message_templates#new
                   edit_message_template GET    /message_templates/:id/edit(.:format)                    message_templates#edit
                        message_template GET    /message_templates/:id(.:format)                         message_templates#show
                                         PUT    /message_templates/:id(.:format)                         message_templates#update
                                         DELETE /message_templates/:id(.:format)                         message_templates#destroy
```

and my _form.erb, looks like this

```
<% form_for(@message_template) do |f| %>
```

but I get this error

```
undefined method `message_templates_path'
```

Comment: What is `@message_template`? More information required.

Comment: When do you get the error?  Initial display of the form or when there's an error or for any form submit?

Comment: You'll also get a better, quicker, more accurate and appropriate answer if you show both the `message_template` model and `controller` code.

Comment: I looked in MessageTemplate it doesn't have belongs_to game, the controller is just a generated controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a new message template for a given game in which case you need to provide the route with the associated game. If it were an existing message template the path would be message_template_path rather than message_templates_path.

Say:

```
<% form_for([@game, @message_template]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Yes I agree.  I edit the answer, adding 'for a given game' for clarity.

Comment: Yes, shallow routes require the parent until the child has been saved and an id (or other param) has been generated. Look for example at your posted routes; new_game_message_template includes the game but edit_message_template doesn't.

Comment: this helped a lot, except for the fact that my controllers have to do more legwork because i'm using friendly id's, I have to do `@game = Game.where(:slug => params[:game_id])` otherwise the foreign key is set to 0 for message_templates.

Comment: Cool, but friendly_id should work with Game.find(params[:game_id]) as normal.